# Создание, заполнение и удаление строк таблицы под выбранной строкой посредством JS

Tags: javascript

На странице сайта есть таблица со списком документов. При клике на документ (ссылка), отправляется запрос в 1С, откуда приходит список товаров (в xml) данного документа. Как можно сделать чтобы появлялись новые строки с этими данными но только под конкретной строкой (по которой кликнули)?

На данный момент максимум чего добился - строки появляются, но только в конце самой таблицы. 
Код ниже:

```
$('#docs #doc_link').click(function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var type = $(this).data('type');
        var product,qty,price,summ;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/costumer/items',
            data: {id:id, type:type},
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function(response) {
                $(response).find('response').each(function(){
                    $(this).find('row').each(function(){
                        $(this).find("product").each(function(){
                            product = $(this).text();
                        });
                        $(this).find("qty").each(function(){
                            qty = $(this).text();
                        });
                        $(this).find("price").each(function(){
                            price = $(this).text();
                        });
                        $(this).find("summ").each(function(){
                            summ = $(this).text();    
                        });
                        $('#docs > tbody').append('<tr><td class="cart_description">' + product + '<td/><td class="cart_total" style="font-size: 18px; padding-top: 5px">' + price + '<td/><td class="cart_total" style="font-size: 18px; padding-top: 5px">' + summ + '<td/></tr>');
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

И как можно при, например, повторном клике их убрать ?

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

UPDATE

Код таблицы:

```
<tbody>
<?php foreach($cos_ord as $order): ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="cart_description">
            <a id="doc_link" data-id="<?= $order['1c_doc_id'] ?>" data-type="<?= $order['1c_doc_type_id'] ?>" href="<?= \yii\helpers\Url::to(['costumer/items', 'id' => $order['1c_doc_id'], 'type' => $order['1c_doc_type_id']]) ?>"><?= $order['1c_doc_name'] ?></a>
        </td>
        <td class="cart_total" style="font-size: 18px; padding-top: 5px">
            <p class="cart_total_price" style="font-size: 18px; padding-top: 5px"><?= $order['1c_doc_sum'] ?> $</p>
        </td>
        <td class="cart_total" style="font-size: 18px; padding-top: 5px">
            <?php if($order['costumer_balance'] == 0): ?>
                <p class="cart_total_price" style="font-size: 18px; padding-top: 5px"> --- </p>
            <?php else: ?>    
                <p class="cart_total_price" style="font-size: 18px; padding-top: 5px"><?= $order['costumer_balance'] ?> $</p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<!-- TABLE FOOTER -->
```

Comment: добавьте разметку таблицы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задачу решил следующим образом(UPDATE с рабочим удалением).

1) Сначала добавил идентификатор к необходимому элементу и на "+" повесил обращение к функции:

```
<tr id="<?= $order['id'] ?>">
<td class="cart_description">
    <p id="doc_link" data-id="<?= $order['1c_doc_id'] ?>" data-type="<?= $order['1c_doc_type_id'] ?>" ><i class="fa fa-plus" onClick="reply_click(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id)"></i> <?= $order['1c_doc_name'] ?></p>

</td>
```

Код формирующий таблицу целиком:

```
<table class="table table-condensed" id="docs">
<thead>
    <tr class="cart_menu">
        <td class="price">Документ</td>
        <td class="total">К-ть</td>
        <td class="total">Сумма документу</td>
        <td class="total">Зміна балансу</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($cos_ord as $order): ?>
        <tr id="<?= $order['id'] ?>">
            <td class="cart_description">
                <?php if($order['1c_doc_type_id'] == 1 || $order['1c_doc_type_id'] == 2): ?>
                    <p id="doc_<?= $order['id'] ?>"><i id="rem_<?= $order['id'] ?>" class="fa fa-plus" onClick="reply_click(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id, this.className)"></i> <?= $order['1c_doc_name'] ?></p>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p id="doc_<?= $order['id'] ?>"> <?= $order['1c_doc_name'] ?></p>
                <?php endif;?>

            </td>
            <td class="cart_total" style="font-size: 18px; padding-top: 5px">
            </td>
            <td class="cart_total" style="font-size: 18px; padding-top: 5px">
                <p class="cart_total_price" style="font-size: 18px; padding-top: 5px"><?= $order['1c_doc_sum'] ?> $</p>
            </td>
            <td class="cart_total" style="font-size: 18px; padding-top: 5px">
                <?php if($order['costumer_balance'] == 0): ?>
                    <p class="cart_total_price" style="font-size: 18px; padding-top: 5px"> --- </p>
                <?php else: ?>    
                    <p class="cart_total_price" style="font-size: 18px; padding-top: 5px"><?= $order['costumer_balance'] ?> $</p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <!-- TABLE FOOTER -->
    <tr>
        <table class="table table-condensed total-result">
            <tr class="shipping-cost">
                <td>Поточний баланс:</td>
                <td><?= $_SESSION['user']->balance ?> USD</td>                                      
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Сумма замовлень з сайту:</td>
                <td><span><?= $total_sum ?> грн</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

2) Потом отредактировал сам скрипт(финальный вид).

```
function reply_click(row_id, el_class){
var id = row_id;
var parent_id = 'doc_'+row_id;
var rem_plus = 'rem_'+row_id;
var row_remove_id = row_id+'_rem';
var rem_minus = row_id+'_rem-';
if (el_class !== 'fa fa-minus'){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/costumer/items',
        data: {id:id},
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(response) {
            $(response).find('response').each(function(){
                $(this).find('row').each(function(){
                    $(this).find("product").each(function(){
                        product = $(this).text();
                    });
                    $(this).find("qty").each(function(){
                        qty = $(this).text();
                    });
                    $(this).find("price").each(function(){
                        price = $(this).text();
                    });
                    $(this).find("summ").each(function(){
                        summ = $(this).text();    
                    }); 
                    $('#'+row_id).after('<tr class="'+row_remove_id+'"><td class="cart_description">' + product + '</td><td class="cart_total" style="font-size: 18px; padding-top: 5px">' + qty + '</td><td class="cart_total" style="font-size: 18px; padding-top: 5px">' + price + '</td><td class="cart_total" style="font-size: 18px; padding-top: 5px">' + summ + '</td></tr>');
                });
                $('#'+rem_plus).remove();
                $('#'+parent_id).prepend('<i id="'+rem_minus+'" class="fa fa-minus" onClick="reply_click(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id, this.className)"></i>');
            });
        }
    });
}else{
    $('.'+row_remove_id).remove();
    $('#'+rem_minus).remove();
    $('#'+parent_id).prepend('<i id="'+rem_plus+'" class="fa fa-plus" onClick="reply_click(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id, this.className)"></i>');
}
```

}

Столкнулся с проблемой: при попытке удалить сгенерированные строки таблицы (все строки относящиеся к конкретному документу имеют ID данного документа), удалялась только одна строка. Проблему удалось побороть посредством назначение не ID для строки а класса(почему то несколько элементов одного класса удалять можно за раз, а вот с ID такой номер не проходит).

Данное решение позволяет динамически создавать и удалять строки таблицы именно под выбранной строкой.

Спасибо всем кто пытался помочь. Всем бобра ;)

Answer (score 0):

Я по сути решил этот вопрос путём передачи id строки таблицы в параметре onclick. Приходящие встают за целевой строкой, но!
Но так, как нет вводных данных по таблице не могу прям конкретно ответить. Дай кусок таблицы, как оно должно выглядеть и что-то можно будет показать.
И да, не делал так:

```
    $('#docs #doc_link').click(function(event)
```

а через кнопку (ссылка)

```
    onclick=(Docs(rowId)) и так далее...
```

Comment: Добавил код таблицы в стартовый топик.

Comment: "onclick=(Docs(rowId)) и так далее..." а можно подробней ? Как передать айди строки ?